# How do I do to sum values in fields with dynamic id?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, sum, advanced-custom-fields

I need to sum the fields of a form. Field ids are dynamic. I need to show the result of the sum in a third field. I would like to know how to do this in PHP or JS.

```
<input type="number" id="acf-field_5a7cb1f6601f3-1-field_5a7cb278601f8" class="" min="0" max="99999" step="any" name="acf[field_5a7cb1f6601f3][1][field_5a7cb278601f8]" value="10" placeholder="">
<input type="number" id="acf-field_5a7cb1f6601f3-2-field_5a7cb278601f8" class="" min="0" max="99999" step="any" name="acf[field_5a7cb1f6601f3][2][field_5a7cb278601f8]" value="12" placeholder="">
<input type="number" id="acf-field_5a7cb1f6601f3-3-field_5a7cb278601f8" class="" min="0" max="99999" step="any" name="acf[field_5a7cb1f6601f3][3][field_5a7cb278601f8]" value="25" placeholder="">
```

I edited to make clear what I need:
[Example Function in PHP display Field of result...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvH9c.jpg)
[Example display result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjTO6.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean sum the fields or sum the values of fields?

Comment: @null sum the values of fields

Comment: @Ele Yes they are dynamic ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let total = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach(el=>total+=+el.value);
document.querySelector('#total').value = total;
console.log(total);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="acf-field_5a7cb1f6601f3-1-field_5a7cb278601f8" class="" min="0" max="99999" step="any" name="acf[field_5a7cb1f6601f3][1][field_5a7cb278601f8]" value="10" placeholder="">
<input type="number" id="acf-field_5a7cb1f6601f3-2-field_5a7cb278601f8" class="" min="0" max="99999" step="any" name="acf[field_5a7cb1f6601f3][2][field_5a7cb278601f8]" value="12" placeholder="">
<input type="number" id="acf-field_5a7cb1f6601f3-3-field_5a7cb278601f8" class="" min="0" max="99999" step="any" name="acf[field_5a7cb1f6601f3][3][field_5a7cb278601f8]" value="25" placeholder="">
<br>
<label for="total">Total: </label>
<input id="total">
```

Don't use the ID, use `document.querySelectorAll(...)` and use any CSS selector you are familiar with. For instance:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach((el)=>{});
```

Comment: @J.Z - I updated the code snippet. If you run it now, you will see the total is put into an input element.

Comment: It worked. but when saved does not store the value in the field =(

Comment: [Complete Code] (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298302/problem-save-values-sum-advanced-custom-fields)

Comment: @J.Z - that is because disabled form fields are not submitted with the form. You have three choices: 1. enabled it always (it will be editable); 2. enable it just prior to form submission via JavaScript; 3. enable it and change the type to hidden (it will not be visible to the user, but will submit).

Comment: Casbum -  How do I display the result in real time when I type the numbers in the fields? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;        
$("input[type=number]").each(function() 
{ 
  if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) 
  {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);            
  }         
});
```

Using JQuery (as you should imo, for the sake of saving yourself compatibility headaches) This will sum the values of all number inputs. You might want to limit that further in the future. Pure JS solution follows:

```
var sum = 0;        
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]").forEach(function() {
  if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) 
  {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);            
  }    
});
```

Comment: The OP did not request an answer regarding jQuery - and you opinion is irrelevant.